# stability, consistency and convergence of trapezoidal method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, numerical-calculus

Ref to problem 11 in chapter 5.11 in Numerical Analysis 9th ed. R. Burden, J. Faires.

The question asks to "Discuss the stability, consistency and convergence of the implicit trapezoidal method." I feel like this question is vague and will split my concerns in three questions.

(1)
For stability, are they asking to compute a stability region or to prove stability through satisfying Lipschitz constant? A-stability was easy to find but the Lipschitz constant I am still finding a hard time understanding how that proves that the method is unconditionally stable for all $h > 0$. Can someone walk me through this?

(2) For consistency, I know the method is consistent if $$\lim_{h->0} |\tau_n / h| = 0$$
where $\tau_n$ is the local truncation error and the order of consistency is given by:
$$\frac{y(t_{n+1}) - y(t_{n})}{h} - \phi(t_n,y(t_n),h)$$
now I got that $\tau_n = \frac{h^3}{3!}y'''(t_n)$ which is $0$ for $h$ -> $0$ which means that the method is consistent. For the order of consistency I am getting the following:
$$\frac{y(t_{n+1}) - y(t_{n})}{h} - \phi(t_n,y(t_n),h) = \frac{h^2}{2}y''(t_n) + O(h^3)$$ which suggests the order of consistency is of order $O(h^2)$. My issue is that one can confirms consistency by having 
$$\phi(t,y,h) = \frac{1}{2}[f(t,y) + f(t+h,y+h)]$$
$$\phi(t,y,0) = \frac{1}{2}[f(t,y) + f(t+0,y+0)] = f(t,y)$$
and since $\phi(t,w,0) = f(t,y)$ the method is considered consistent. This seems too trivial, can someone explain this further and maybe show me how it's applied to the trapezoidal rule?

(3) Lastly, it's said that if the method is stable and consistent then it will converge. Can someone confirm this and show me how to calculate the order of convergence?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason that you get 2 different results for the truncation error? The first is slightly wrong, there should be a division by $h$; the second is completely from the Euler method.

Comment: so the method is consistent if the $\lim_{h->0} |\tau_n /h | = 0 $ correct? what would be the trapezoidal counterpart to the second one?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the change between $τ_n/h$ and $τ_n$ alone, I thought the big formula was for $τ_n$. The first formula is correct, then $\frac{τ_n}{h}=\frac{h^2}6y'''(\tilde t_n)=\frac{h^2}6y'''( t_n)+O(h^3)$ gives the order as $2$.

Comment: Okay cool! I think I am getting confused between order of accuracy and order of error. Trap method is second order accurate with third order error correct? The LTE found online (https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs370/notes/LTE.pdf) gave $\tau_n = O(h^3)$

Comment: The error of one step is $O(h^3)$. This is usual for all methods, a method of order $p$ has a local error of $O(h^{p+1})$, in the sum of steps the error from time $t_0$ to time $t$ is, in a first approximation, $O(h^p(t-t_0))$, for the one-step error we have $t-t_0=h$. It is best to always focus on the global error order to avoid this confusion.

Comment: makes sense! thank you so much for your help! Is there an explicit way to calculate global error from truncation error or is saying that the collective sum of all errors up to a time $t_f$ is always of order $O(h^p)$ or in this case $O(h^2)$

Comment: Look at the diverse proofs of the global error. For nice equations you get $c'(t)=\partial_yf(t,y(t))c(t)-\frac{1}6y'''(t)$ for the leading term $c(t)h^2$ in the global error at time $t$.

Comment: Thanks man! I will take a look at some resources tonight

Answer (score 1):

(2) The simplified approach is a theorem about multi-step methods. The trapezoidal method has that form.

(3) The order of convergence is the order of consistency, if convergence is established. The order $2$ you found is correct, even if the second consistency/local truncation error formula you did it with is wrong.

Comment: which would be the correct formulas in that case? The LTE i got from https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs370/notes/LTE.pdf

Comment: The formula in the consistency confirmation is correct, the one in the order computation is wrong and belongs to the Euler methods.

Comment: oh okay! thanks for the clarification and appreciate the help! How would one compute the order of consistency for the trapezoidal method in that case?